# Which display manager is used by default in Ubuntu GNOME 16.04?

Tags: lightdm, gdm, ubuntu-gnome, display-manager

I can't find this information, and while trying to install the nvidia drivers for my laptop, I got a message explaining that I had 2 display managers installed, and that seemed strange.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ubuntu GNOME uses GDM as its default display manager.

This can be verified by looking at the dependencies for the **ubuntu-gnome-desktop** package, which include **gdm3** but not lightdm.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-gnome-desktop

Comment: Thanks, so this is nvidia-prime which depends on lightdm and force-install it

Comment: Yes, nvidia-prime not recognizing gdm3 is a [bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1582439). It's an easy fix so hopefully it will be fixed for Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS before long.

Comment: Nick, please include the nvidia information in your answer to make it even better

Comment: @RamonSuarez If you'd like to include that information in my answer, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: This answer is confusing. gdm != gdm3. Which is the default?

Comment: The `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` package in 16.04 depends on the `gdm3` package, which supplies Gnome Display Manager, currently version 3.18.3-0ubuntu2 (for Xenial, anyway). See http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gdm3